# C: How come adding an int to an empty variable results in random numbers

Tags: c

New to C, when I run this code - something unexpected happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add();

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n",add(3));
}

int add(int i, int j)
{
    return i+j;
}
```

I understand that I am not providing a second parameter to the add function. Out of curiosity though, can anyone tell me why calling the function with only 1 parameter supplied continues to return random numbers, such as 2127001435...612806891...-395221029?

Comment: Undefined behavior. What you're doing invokes undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "empty variable".

Comment: Uninitialized variables, by default, will store garbage values. @John Bollinger, it looks like 'uninitialized' is what OP meant.

Comment: The second argument (`j`) is initialized with whatever random leftover happens to be in the memory allocated for `j` at the time when the `add(3)` function is called.

Comment: As far as i know this should generate a compiler error, you shouldn't be able to run it in C
Are you sure that add(int i) isn't defined in your code?

Comment: Memory is never empty. Some junk remains on the stack after initialization code and this is what `add` uses as a _random number_

Comment: Are you really saying that this code compiles?

Comment: If you fix the function declaration to match the definition, the program won't even compile, since you're passing the wrong number of arguments. Declaring it with an empty argument list disables argument checking.

Comment: @Jacopo AFAIK `int add();` declares a function returning `int` that takes 0 or more arguments. So it should compile (though I haven't checked). A sane compiler should throw a warning however.

Comment: @RudyM: `j` is not _uninitialised_, but is not passed at all, i.e. it does not exist at all.

Comment: What compiler, compiler flags?

Comment: @tangrs it compiles in GCC 4.9.1!!!

Comment: This is deprecated since 27 years and a compiler shall warn about it since 17 years.

Comment: @Jacopo, it's not surprising that the code compiles.  That would be different if the first declaration of function `add()` provided a prototype.

Comment: The declaration in the top is not correct. This code, written in a good way, would never compile.

Comment: @AFR, the declaration at the top *is* correct, it just doesn't provide a prototype.  It does not mean the same thing as `int add(void);`.

Comment: @axiac thanks for that explanation, that's more what I was getting at, I just wanted to understand the behavior

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know is ok, but is not ok for the purpouse of this program. If he wants to add two Integers, where is the reason to declare the function without the correct argument count?

Comment: funny pickles of programing!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you break the rules of the language and the program compiles, its behavior is *undefined* (i.e., anything can happen).

```
int add();
```

tells the compiler to allow you to call `add` with anything, but you still 
must ensure that if the function definition accepts two `ints`, you will call it with **exactly** two `ints`.

Declarations with empty parameters are sometimes useful, but in 99% of cases you want to avoid them.

If you replace the declaration with this one

```
int add(int, int);
```

the compiler should save you from, or at least warn you about, your error.

(Additionally, declarations with typed parameters will make the compiler convert unfitting parameters if it can (e.g., if you were to call your `add` function with a `long`, then with the typed declaration, the `long` argument will get implicitly converted to `int`. This won't happen if the declaration is `int add();`))

Answer (score 8):

Most of the answers focuses on the technical reasons on why you're getting the results you're seeing. However, for a newbie to C, they're probably not very useful answers since they're a bit hard to understand without some experience in C.

The more gentle explanation is that you need to understand that the C language has some rules that you have to follow and promises you need to keep. If you decide not to follow these rules, the compiler is at liberty to do whatever it wants. This is what we call *undefined behaviour*.

In your code: `int add();` you've promised the compiler that there exists a function somewhere that returns `int` that takes some unspecified number of arguments.

You've then defined the function to take *exactly two arguments*. So now you've (in a sense) promised that the `add` function will work correctly as long as you pass in exactly two arguments (of type `int`).

Later you call the function `add(3);` with one argument. Because you've passed only one argument to a function that is defined to take exactly two, the compiler can do anything it wants (in this case, return random numbers). It can do this because you broke your promise that you have to pass two arguments to `add`.

Generally, to catch these problems earlier (i.e. the compiler can warn us when we're about to do something silly), we use more strict definitions for functions.

Contrast `a` with `b`, `c`, `d` which are more strict.

```
int a();             // a takes ??? arguments
int b(void);         // b takes exactly zero arguments
int c(int x);        // c takes exactly one argument
int d(int x, int y); // d takes exactly two arguments
```

Comment: Your characterization of the meaning of `int add();` is not quite correct.  It doesn't say that the function can take any number of arguments.  Rather, it says that the function accepts an *unspecified* (but fixed) number of arguments of unspecified types.

Comment: Well explained. This answer ought to get more votes than mine.

Comment: tangrs, I suspect you're replying in part to my point. I upvoted this because in principle you're right - if this is a newbie don't bamboozle with irrelevant detail. I'll edited my comment - I think it is important for newbie's to get out of the mindset that you program the machine when in truth you only program the compiler which codes the machine.

Answer (score 2):

First, we *declare* `foo` as a function taking an unspecified number of arguments and returning an integer:

```
int add();
```

We *call* it with one argument:

```
  add(3)
```

But then we *define* it as taking two arguments:

```
int add(int i, int j)
{
    ...
}
```

Because we called it without providing the second argument, our program has undefined behaviour, and so what happens is unpredictable.  On your system, the result varies from run to run.  On other systems, you may get consistent output, or you could get a runtime error (e.g. via a signal).

In the general case, the definition of `foo()` could be in a different translation unit to `main()`, so it's not possible for a compiler to reliably detect this problem in C (in C++, the argument type signature is part of the function linkage, so the situation there differs).

Comment: No, calling a function with the wrong number of arguments produces undefined behavior in and of itself.  You cannot reason about whether `j` is initialized in the function as a result of such a call because *nothing* about the semantics of the call is defined.

Comment: Serves me right for playing it safe - I couldn't remember whether it's undefined or merely unspecified.  Should've looked it up before answering!

Answer (score 0):

As tangrs points out in comments, the behavior is undefined so any behavior is allowable... but that's not exactly what you asked, and the more complete answer does convey a few insights...

So while any behavior is allowable, why are you getting *this* behavior?

Well, a more strict language wouldn't compile that call, because the signature is messed up.  But C is not a more strict language.  It assumes you know what you're doing.

What you're doing is telling it to construct a stack frame for a function that takes a single integer argument, put a particular value in the right place in the stack frame for the function to see it as "the value for the parameter", and then call the function.

But the function expects two arguments.  That is, it expects the caller to have prepared a stack frame with two integer parameters.  Where it expects to find the first one, it finds the first one.  Where it expects to find the second one, it finds... whatever value was last in the memory that *would've* contained the 2nd parameter if the call were correct.

The stack frame is smaller than what was expected, and the value for the expected 2nd parameter would have been placed past the end of the stack frame that was actually prepared.  So that's where the function looks for it and it finds... whatever random value was already there.  Because of how the call stack grows and shrinks, different invocations will find different values.

Comment: No, not really.  You can write such an explanation for a given C implementation, or even for a class of C implementations, but C itself has nothing whatever to say about stacks, nor even about how the arguments given in a function call are conveyed to the function in general.  You cannot explain or reason about undefined behavior at the C level.  That's more or less what "undefined" means.

Comment: Question didn't ask about the C spec.  It asked why the asker got a particular behavior.  Your objection is academic in this context.

Comment: The question is tagged [C], and not with any particular implementation.  Any answer must be interpreted in that light.

Comment: Furthermore, without reference to a specific implementation, your answer is speculative.  It is not necessarily correct even for systems that operate with a call stack (which indeed is the only kind the OP is likely to be using).  The actual behavior is probably something like that, but not necessarily exactly that.

Comment: The question is tagged C; that does not make it a question about the C spec.  The question is why the behavior occurred, period.  As to your later comment... if you'd like to place a wager, I'm game.  Doesn't change the fact that my answer is useful where as yours is pedantic and uninformative.

Comment: Every C question is about the C spec.  We cannot even have the conversation outside the context of the language specification.  As for usefulness, I posit that in the big picture it is more useful to encourage people to think about their programs' behavior in terms of what the standard demands (or doesn't) and what it promises in return, than to focus on implementation details.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: Typically compilers put arguments (it varies but typically the first 4-6 arguments and thereafter on the stack) into registers. A stack frame typically starts at the beginning of a function. Arguments passed onto the stack lie within the callers stack frame (by convention) not the callee's. Pedantic I know but worth mentioning - if you're a pedant;)

Comment: @JohnBollinger - "What in the C spec would explain this behavior" is a question about the spec. This question is why the user, while writing C, got this result. As for usefulness: "This specific source doesn't give an answer" is not more useful than an answer.  Understanding how cavalier C is about giving you values form uninitialized memory is important for exactly the reasons you think harping on the spec is important, with the bonus that people are more likely to actually pay attention with concrete examples of what can go wrong.  Both pieces of information should be given; so I did.  Deal.

Answer (score -1):

In C a block of memory is allocated to the variable.
because no value was provided to it, the block of memory that has been allocated to the variable still contains some value which is left over from previous program.
This value id called 'GARBAGE VALUE'
here when you add i and j without initializing j, the garbage value is being  added with i and returned as result.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of the answers are excellent and cut to the chase. Taking on board tangrs answer: the reason for the detail was to help explain why you get undefined behavior in the context of what the compiler is doing with your code.

It depends on the platform and compiler. But typically for a few arguments a called function will expect the parameters to reside in a number of - particular - registers (or sometimes on the stack). These can have any old garbage in them depending on what they were last used for. So if you're not providing a value or initialized variable to be moved into them, they will be using what values were last "assigned" to them. And it is anybody's guess what those values are.